# GKE Cluster hangs while trying to delete it

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I do have an GKE Cluster where the node-pool is already deleted, but while deleting the cluster it hangs endless (since 1 month).

Deleting the cluster using `gcloud container clusters delete clusername` does not work

```
 - [clusername] in [europe-west4-a]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.delete) Some requests did not succeed:
 - ResponseError: code=400, message=Operation operation-1690195702232-2db62bae-d4c9-40ef-9156-f495f41be875 is currently upgrading cluster clusername. Please wait and try again once it is done.
```

Thats why I listed all operations ( `gcloud container operations list`), and try to cancel them.

When I try to cancel the operation `gcloud container operations cancel operation-1690195702232-2db62bae-d4c9-40ef-9156-f495f41be875` (Target xxxx-np does not exist anymore) I got the following error

```
Are you sure you want to cancel operation operation-1690195702232-2db62bae-d4c9-40ef-9156-f495f41be875?

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

ERROR: (gcloud.container.operations.cancel) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Only node upgrade operations can be cancelled.
- @type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo
  requestId: '0xc37b99720c0f0b46'
```

In the Cloud Console it looks like this (for one month)

[image]

I've no further idea how to rid of this cluster.  It seems the delete is blocked by an update operation which could not be done because the node-pool does not exist anymore.

Does anybody have an idea how I can delete this cluster?

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Can you try to create a single node with previous specifications, upgrade it and then delete the cluster. If this also didn't work try to raise a support ticket with gcp team they might have provision to delete the cluster in the backend.

Comment: Adding a node is not possible, everthing is blocked.  As we do have only "basic" support there is no way to contact the google support team, unfortunatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague resolved the issue for me. It turns out a "Global Load Balancer" was connected to a service in the cluster which no longer existed,  preventing its deletion. Once we removed the load balancer, the cluster was deleted immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue and managed to get past it by deleting everything in my cluster. Just run through deleting all namespaces. You'll probably have resources with finalizers that need to be removed, but this did the trick for my team.